# RLLib Rendering

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I'm trying to render a custom environment using ray RRLib in Python.

I'm trying to run some example code found at
[github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/examples/env_rendering_and_recording.py](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/examples/env_rendering_and_recording.py) .
I also tried to run an experiment with a simple 1d corridor based on a gymnasium `Box`. It gives me the error  ``` WARNING env_runner_v2.py:297 -- Could not import gymnasium.envs.classic_control.rendering! Try ``pip install gymnasium[all]``. ``` No rendering windows or other images showed up. I tried pip install gymnasium[all] and repeated, and the result was the same. Can anyone suggest what is going wrong here?